# AsyncTask Error -- out of order maybe?

Tags: java, android, json, android-asynctask

I have close to 0 experience with AsyncTasks, so keep that in mind!

I'm trying to get to an external database through a web service so I know I have to use an AsyncTask. [Here's my code](http://pastebin.com/RwD5ZcmE). At line 73, for some reason, everything just breaks.

[Here's the log file](http://pastebin.com/uwPBMSQ0), the exceptions start getting thrown at line 73 of my code. When I try to debug by stepping through the code, I keep getting 'source not found'.

Maybe I'm not understanding how AsyncTasks worked, but I assumed that after line 67, my JSONArray object 'json' gets set and then I can use it after that line...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Do not create a class in `onCreate()` method, class is always higher structure than a method.

You have NPE bc asynctask take some time to be done, so just run your task and on `onPostExecute()` do your parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Your failing at line 73 b/c your AsyncTask hasn't instantiated the json variable by the time you are trying to use it.  Remember, AsnycTask is running on a separate process, any work that needs to be done with the json variable needs to be done in the onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask.  This method runs on the UI thread so it's ok to do UI work there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends **AsyncTask** outside the **onCreate()**. (Not only in this scenario) you always need to create the class outside the method(except some cases like anonymous inner classes, of course it's again another big discussion). Then have the AsyncTask class's object created in the onCreate() method and with that object you call `execute()` method to run that task in a different thread. As per your code you are unable to differentiate the things. In the **doInBackground()** you write the code to get the data that needs to be run on different thread and in the **onPostExecute()** method you get the data that you got from the doInBackground and updates the UI. To update the UI you can use **runOnUIThread()** as shown below.. Below is the pseudo code(untested) as per your requirement..

```
public class AllEventActivity extends Activity {

    private ListView listView1;
    private String tag = "all";
    private JSONArray json;
    View header;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



                List<AllEvent> weather_data = new ArrayList<AllEvent>();
//        AllEvent weather_data[] = new AllEvent[]
//        {
//            new AllEvent(R.drawable.a, "Soccer Field"),        
//        };


                weather_data.add(new AllEvent(R.drawable.a, "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"));


        listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1); //

        header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);

        new All_Events_DB_Connect().execute(new String[] {"all"});

    }

    class All_Events_DB_Connect extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray>
    {

            @Override
            protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... arg0)
            {
                    String tag = arg0[0];
                    UserFunctions u = new UserFunctions();
                    //JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
                    try
                    {
                            json = u.getAllEvents(tag);

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return json;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray arr)
            {
                    //returnedJson = json;
                    json = arr;

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                             JSONObject j = new JSONObject();

                             for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
                             {
                                     try
                                     {
                                             j = json.getJSONObject(i);
                                             Toast.makeText(this, j.getString("hostName"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                     }
                                     catch (Exception e)
                                     {
                                             Log.e("JSON Error", e.getMessage());
                                     }
                             }


                            AllEventAdapter adapter = new AllEventAdapter(this,
                                    R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);

                            listView1.addHeaderView(header);

                            listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                    });
            }
    }
}
```